# form_state['values'] generating error undefined index: values

Tags: 7

I am having a simple form like this. I want to read the ID value in the middle of the form. When I try to get it using `$fromvalues = $form_state['values']['id'];` it gives the following error:

> Undefined Index: values in `templates_form()`

```
function templates_form_add($form, &$form_state, $templates = NULL) {
  $templates = entity_get_controller('templates')->create();     
  return templates_form($form, $form_state, $templates); 
 }

 function templates_form($form, &$form_state, $templates) {
   $form = array();

   $form['id'] = array(
     '#title' => t('ID'),
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#default_value' => isset($templates->id) ? $templates->id : '',
     '#description' => t('Unique Id'),
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#maxlength' => 255,
     '#disabled'=> empty($ntemplates->id) ? FALSE : TRUE,
   );

   $fromvalues= $form_state['values'];

   $form['city'] = array(
     '#title' => t('city'),
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#options' => $cities,
     '#default_value' => isset($templates->city) ? $templates->city: '',
     '#required' => TRUE,
     '#maxlength' => 255,
     '#disabled'=> empty($templates->id) ? FALSE : TRUE,

   ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates precisely what is going on: during the initial call of `templates_form()` the `$form_state['values']` does not yet exist. This will exist in a future ajax call (if you do ajax) and in validate and submit functions. You better check if it exists first with `isset` or `empty`.